# Laravel 5.3 Pusher notifications not received by Echo

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, pusher

I'm trying to broadcast a simply test notification to a Laravel app using 
   Pusher.Within my web page, I've got this JavaScript to listen for the 
  broadcast in bootstrap.js

```
 import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'notmyrealpusherkey',
    encrypted: true
});
```

This is my Notification.vue

```
Echo.private('App.User.' + this.id)
    .notification((notification) => {
        console.log(notification);
        toastr.info(notification.message, notification.subject);
    });
```

My BroadcastServiceProvider is configured to validate the private channel request:

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.{id}', function ($user, $id) {
    return (int)$user->id === (int)$id;
});
```

> When I check the Pusher console, I can see that the code above successfully subscribed check image here:
>   [https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_76665/NvEB7BgUnmIA2IR5rO1S3gF1aSP306/Pusher%2B-%2BDebug%2Bconsole%2B2016-12-28%2B19-37-19.png?Expires=1510590716&Signature=Cgykr97sBJUqljH02DfUJztcILiFTMUsUBfsF4kXoYsuJCsHf4lG-3tyhXBmCM70rWGyeCqZ7nrkgqYuOYEYs6Q41nq-ActI9B-vt6fhh5rYgekfe-HM0dERY67OqAbaLVfskq2mUp1Zl7yBPKwgNR9Fw0uzdH8q6ia9L0Za9QBLM1u6Fq3AHoN4OodJaXr5X-ifn1ZVAC7WsYVtLcnWpr3Yx0-w2nzbS4rD2S9KtMnIpsOA8bcHHWW3qoDFm5J0hIB6GVF42-vQTUNo~4B1~L8XT41coOarsF~sTVsaWTYINX93BmpVpKUEDyoarbffEuUsf4sZO6Ee5fILK1wJOQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4C5M.png)
>
> When i send notification directly from pusher it will send on console but not send using trigger the image link in description:
>   [https://d1ro8r1rbfn3jf.cloudfront.net/ms_76665/kxgC93iHRWnMPHIdJehBgfsfUG47Lu/Pusher%2B-%2BDebug%2Bconsole%2B2016-12-28%2B19-37-56.png?Expires=1510592071&Signature=f8wvoKGnWLROJ0cXCWqkWz3EVL6rVj6PuJ~-gXpHHgrt7FlZ9gf9YO3lezW2dplmN08419w9qWJh-Cc7cpt4B1dEEwqORjL8eRz528B6l-HKHwnn96iCIE~bfwc80L9qJx9nBbLqTqnEkAlvbugcGlIrr1zB-iMlz9TMloLpYkq-2T-a1Ww8BM3SmbETVunLqhqYxUCbgK3T1swS135tqvg36sA8FWWnBe3djHgSTUuYS6Nv8MyvkF8JS1slxtMzsJ30oEzs5zc~QhEfECfoA8On8VIHP8a4VrOjUyElcrcPHG~7TwnYP8Ajje7O7EW9SNyIV7t3LSyxBGiIdsVDtQ__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJHEJJBIZWFB73RSA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqc8m.png)

The NewFriendRequest is just a simple test notification:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Notifications;

 use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
 use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
 use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

 class NewFriendRequest extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
 {
use Queueable;

public $user;

/**
 * Create a new notification instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}

/**
 * Get the notification's delivery channels.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function via($notifiable)
{
    return ['mail','broadcast','database'];
}

/**
 * Get the mail representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
 */
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
                ->line('You received a new friend request from ' . $this->user->name)
                ->action('View Profile', route('profile', ['slug' => $this->user->slug]))
                ->line('Thank you for using our Tictac!');
}

/**
 * Get the array representation of the notification.
 *
 * @param  mixed  $notifiable
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->user->name,
        'message' => $this->user->name . ' sent you friend request.'
     ];
}


  }
```

I also tried triggering it from the Laravel side, but it still doesn't reach the user's browser:

```
  $resp =  Auth::user()->add_friend($id);
User::find($id)->notify(new \App\Notifications\NewFriendRequest(Auth::user()));
return $resp;
```

Comment: Please remove the quotes and properly format your code. It's hard to read. Also, your links are broken.

Comment: i have edit my code plz see it. i am tired why i facing this proble..

Comment: Is your event (not the client subscription) reaching Pusher's console?

Comment: no. it not reach. but notification save in database.

Comment: The answer is literally in the docs. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the `toBroadcast()` method in your Notification, [as stated by the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/notifications#broadcast-notifications).

```
class NewFriendRequest extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    public function toBroadcast($notifiable)
    {
        return new BroadcastMessage([
            'message' => 'Insert your message',
            'subject' => 'Insert your subject',
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i have use toArray function to return the broadcast data in console

Comment: public function toArray($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'name' => $this->user->name,
        'message' => $this->user->name . ' sent you friend request.'
     ];
}

Comment: i am using laravel 5.5, pusher 3.0

Comment: when i use your code and run pap artisan queue:work command it show error class  [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
  Class 'App\Notifications\BroadcastMessage' not found